# Swapping Between Multiple GTM Codes

Tags: google-tag-manager

So my use case is this:

I have GTM set up on a website. Within the website, there is "Select Store" screen, where you can select a different store, and it will send you to that store's version of the website.

What I want to do, is have the separate GTM codes for each store. So on store A's version of the website, it would fire events to "GTM-STORECODEA", then when you swap to store B, it sends events to "GTM-STORECODEB" instead (If the store had the Google Tag Manager code defined).

My initial plan for switching stores was to have the  responsible for the gtm firing GTM codes be added to the page if we change stores to a store that has a store level GTM code.

Then when switching stores, that script would then be removed, and if the new store has a store, a new script is created and then inserted into the body.

It seems however, that removing the script element does NOT stop the events from firing, so what ends up happening is when I swap from store A to B, the events will fire for both codes. I'm guessing this has to do with the fact that you cannot unload javascript from html.

A potential workaround I thought of, is to create a unique datalayer for every store, by setting the datalayer to the GTM id  and then having every gtag request sent to it's corresponding store data layer. This seems very hacky though and would be incredibly messy to implement in my case, so I'm hoping there's another viable alternative.

Update:
For anyone wondering, I ended up using a hard refresh to "clear" the lingering GTM scripts.